# Well Functioning Calculator in python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

```
# Returns the sum of First_Value and Second_Value
def add(First_Value, Second_Value, Third_Value, Fourth_Value, Fifth_Value):
    return First_Value + Second_Value + Third_Value + Fourth_Value + Fifth_Value

# Returns the result of subtracting First_Value - Second_Value
def sub(First_Value, Second_Value, Third_Value, Fourth_Value, Fifth_Value):
        return First_Value - Second_Value - Third_Value - Fourth_Value - Fifth_Value

# Returns the result of dividing First_Value / Second_Value
def div(First_Value, Second_Value, Third_Value, Fourth_Value, Fifth_Value):
        return First_Value / Second_Value / Third_Value / Fourth_Value / Fifth_Value

# Returns the result of multiplying First_Value * Second_Value
def mul(First_Value, Second_Value, Third_Value, Fourth_Value, Fifth_Value):
        return First_Value * Second_Value * Third_Value * Fourth_Value * Fifth_Value


def main():
    operation = input('What do you want to do? (+,-,*,/)): ')
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
    #invalid operation
        print('You must enter a valid information')
    else:
        Var1 = int(input('Enter First_Value: '))
        Var2 = int(input('Enter Second_Value: '))
        Var3 = int(input('Enter Third_Value: '))
        Var4 = int(input('Enter Fourth_Value: '))
        Var5 = int(input('Enter Fifth_Value: '))
        if(operation == '+'):
            print(add(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5))
        elif(operation == '-'):
            print(sub(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5))
        elif(operation == '/'):
            print(div(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5))
        else:
            print(mul(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5))

main()
```

How can I make this calculating code solve infinite algorithm or inputs?

Comment: Please add a description about what you code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PEP-8

Your code does not really follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- Function and variable names should be *lowercase_with_underscores*.

### "Weird" functions

Your functions are very specifically crafted for just **one** situation. It would be better to use `add(*args, **kwargs):` (as an example for `add()`). This way, if a user wants to add only two or three (or 10000) values together, they don't have to rewrite your code.

### if __name__ == "__main__":

It is common to make `main()` conditional, that is, putting it in an if-statement to make sure it does not execute if the code is imported.

### Exception handling

You should make use of `try:` / `except:` statements to handle exceptions. Now, if a user enters a character that isn't a number, the program will raise a ValueError and exit.

### Operation not in operations

You can improve `main()` by using `if operation not in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:`. This makes it easier to read and maintain-